# How to order git grep results

Tags: git

I would like to order results returned by `git grep` using some git-related criteria, for example the commit date.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK `git grep` searches the work tree, not the entire history.

Comment: Check here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log, there is Commit Ordering section and many other things you could do. Hope that helps

Comment: @GolfWolf: Yes, that is true - `git grep` searches the current work tree, but that would be sufficient for me.

Comment: Use tools like `sort` or `awk` on the results of `git grep` and sort them on your own

Comment: @justMe: Thanks, that definitely helps with searching the entire history. I can use something like `git log -p -G 'pattern'` and the resulting commits are topologically ordered by default. However, it is not as convenient to use as `git grep` because it shows the entire diff of the affected commits. If the output from `git log` could be shortened to only show the lines matched by `-S` switch, it would be sufficient. I can simply pipe it to a plain grep, but then it is not easy to keep the matching line and the commit reference together.

Comment: @SriniV: That would not help, because I need to order it using git-related criteria.

Comment: Try `for commit in $(git log -S <pattern> --pretty=%H);do git grep <pattern> $commit;done`. Extra options could be added to `git log` and `git grep` to limit and format the output.

Comment: @ElpieKay: Thanks. This works reasonably well. It is quite complicated and perhaps slow, but still probably the most complete solution suggested so far.